# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents'

Tags: python, list, nlp, attributeerror, named-entity-recognition

**I am using this code and get the csv file as a list into doc [].**

```
doc = []
with open(r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Final project\Requirements1.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
for riga in csv_reader:
    for campo in riga:
        print(campo)
        doc.append(nlp(campo))
```

**But, When I do the named entity recognition for this using this code below,**

```
for entity in doc.ents:
print(entity.text, entity.label)
```

**I am getting this error.**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents'
```

**What should I do about this? Please help me.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycJJT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
docs = [] # NOTE THIS CHANGED
with open(r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Final project\Requirements1.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
for riga in csv_reader:
    for campo in riga:
        print(campo)
        docs.append(nlp(campo))

# now to get the ner results...

for doc in docs:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.label)
```

Comment: sorry to say that there is no answer from this

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory - you made an ordinary Python list of objects called "doc".  A Python list has no attribute called "ents".

Simply iterate through the elements in the list like this:

```
for entity in doc:
    print(entity.text, entity.label)
```

Provided your list elements indeed have attributes 'text' and 'label' this should work
(can't verify from the code shown that they do have those attributes)

Comment: This is providing me the same error. I cannot give a text for the doc variable. Because my task is to get this as a csv file and preprocess it.Is there any other way to do this named entity recognition for a doc [].

Comment: You created a list called doc,. and appended objects to that list that are the results of nlp(campo). What are the attributes of one of those objects? "doc" is just a Python list -whatever issue you are having comes from the contents of that list.

Comment: There is no issue occurred with displaying the doc.

Comment: No friend. this is the same issue that I have found early. your answer is not clear

Comment: I reread your question . To quote: " I am getting this error. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents' What should I do about this? "  I answered that question. You seem to have another question now.

Comment: " I cannot give a text for the doc variable" is a separate issue, and it isn't clear to me what you mean by that. I am trying to help but your question needs to be clearer.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ents' this is the error I have got again and again.

Comment: Paisano can you help me with my NLP assginment